# c# Populate Collection in Form Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a custom form control which I am trying to pre-populate a collection when the form is created. The collection works fine when the collection gets initialized in the constructor. Once I add an item to the collection inside the constructor, it makes the collection read-only. I have noticed that if i Create a generic control with this same behavior, the collection can still be edited. How can I add items to the collection and still have it be editable through the designer?

Example Code

```cs
public class FormEx : Form
{
    public FormEx()
    {
        tests = new StringCollection();
        tests.Add("Test"); //Sets Collection to Read-Only in the Form Control
    }

    private StringCollection tests;

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public StringCollection Tests
    {
        get
        {
            return tests;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it gets Read-Only?

Comment: What behaviour did you expect?

Comment: what are you asking ? I dont see a question here

Comment: I expected it to not be read-only. I would like the collection to be edited through the collection editor.

Comment: May be you need `set` on `public StringCollection Tests` ?

Comment: That gets handled by the Collection so the set is not needed. Just to humor myself, I did add the set to the Tests property and that did not solve the problem. The collection is still set to read-only.

Comment: Any reason you chose `StringCollection` vs. `List<string>`?  the Add method won't change a collection to read-only, otherwise it would be a useless collection of 1 item.  Can you show us the code that attempts to add an item to the collection that doesn't work?

Comment: I did try the method of List<string> when using a form. It did not work. When adding anything to a collection does not work in the constructor and the example code above is what does not work. In my environment, I am not actually using a StringCollection but a very large custom class with a custom collection, a collection editor, and an item converter. The reason i did not put that in the code above is because 1. it is about 1000 lines of code and 2. the behavior is the same with any collection or list when creating a custom FORM.

Comment: I could not even show the custom property of the `FormEx` in the properties window, it's strange. It ignores all the attributes, just the default properties of the base class `Form` are shown.

Comment: Harrison, I did end up testing out some more of the List<CustomClass> method within my application and for some reason, the first time I tried it, it made my collection read-only but then I played around with it again and it worked as i thought it should. THANK YOU!!